# How to bind on properties of a named slot

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, slot

Referring to [this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoFz7.png), i am trying to implement the same example of `Scoped Slots`provided in the url.
as shown in the following code snippet, i created the slot named `scopedSlot` and specified some properties `text` and `count`:

```
<footer>
    <slot name="footer"></slot>
    <div>
      <slot name="scopedSlot" :text="greetingMessage" :count="1"></slot>
    </div>
</footer>
```

in the `App.vue`, i am trying to bind on the properties of the slot as shown in the following code snippet:

```
<template #scopedSlot v-slot="slotProps">
  {{slotProps.text}} {{ slotProps.count }}
</template>
```

but the latter code generates the following error on `v-slot`:

```
An element cannot have multiple 'v-slot' directives
```

please let me know how to correctly bind on a slot properties

**App**:

```
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js App"/>

  <BaseLayer_0>
    <template #header>
      <h1>header</h1>
    </template>

    <template #default>
      <p>default</p>
    </template>

    <template #footer>
      <p>footer</p>
    </template>

    <template #scopedSlot v-slot="slotProps">
      {{slotProps.text}} {{ slotProps.count }}
    </template>
    
  </BaseLayer_0>

</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import BaseLayer_0 from './components/BaseLayer_0.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
    BaseLayer_0
  }
}
</script>
```

**BaseLayer_0**

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <header>
        <slot name="header"></slot>
    </header>

    <main>
        <slot></slot>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <slot name="footer"></slot>
        <div>
          <slot name="scopedSlot" :text="greetingMessage" :count="1"></slot>
        </div>
    </footer>

  

</template>

<script>
```

export default {
name: 'BaseLayer_0',

}

**image**:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```html
<template #scopedSlot="slotProps">
```

or

```html
<template v-slot:scopedSlot="slotProps">
```

The `#` is shorthand for `v-slot:`, so in your initial code, you were assigning to the scopedSlot without using slotProps, and then again to the default slot, this time using slotProps, and Vue complained.

Comment: would you please have a look at the screen-shot i added, it shows that only the "count" property is showing up but the "text" is not

Comment: Is `greetingMessage` empty?

Comment: according to my understanding, as {{slotProps.text}} is declared in App.vue, then the interpolation will occur as follows: {{slotProps.text}}=>"greetingMessage", hence "greetingMessage" should be displayed, am i mistaken please?

Comment: That is correct. My guess is that `greetingMessage` is displayed, but the variable contains an empty string. I need more details or even a playground link if guessing is not enough.

Comment: i tried to modify the `slotProps` to `scoptedSlotProps` but it did not work,,,is `slotProps` as standard name please

Comment: That's just a variable name, you can use whatever you want, or even use destructuring, i.e. `#scopedSlot="{text, count}"`

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, in `BaseLayer_0.vue`, in the

`<slot name="scopedSlot" :text="greetingMessage" :count="1"></slot>` section,

you used the shorthand `:` for `v-bind` to bind the `text` attribute. Therefore, `greetingMessage` is treated as a variable, but you haven't declared the `greetingMessage` variable in the script.

Hence, you need to add the following:

```
#BaseLayer_0.vue

<script>
export default { 
  name: 'BaseLayer_0',
  data() {
    return {
      greetingMessage: 'hello word'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Secondly**, in the following code snippet, there is also an issue:

```
#app.vue

<template #scopedSlot v-slot="slotProps">
   {{slotProps.text}} {{ slotProps.count }}
</template>
```

It should be corrected to:

```
<template #scopedSlot="{ text, count }">
   {{ text }} {{ count }}
</template>
```

[codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-76429058-6uo91h?file=/src/App.vue)